# SSL (https) for multiple applications (on several subdomains)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, https, lets-encrypt

Consider following scenario:

- I'm owner of domain, say, `example.com`, bought and being administrated in GoDaddy
- I host our company's website on AWS S3, under `example.com`
- I host our company's app frontend (another AWS S3) under `app.example.com`
- I host our company's app testing environment frontend (another AWS S3) under `testapp.example.com`
- I host our company's app backend (AWS Beanstalk) under `back.example.com:8080`
- I host our company's app testing envrionment backend (another AWS Beanstalk) under `testback.example.com:8080`

My domain example.com points to S3 bucket using domain forwarding (forward with masking). All the `*.example.com` subdomains are handled with DNS CNAME records.

Now I want to enable HTTPS for our applcation. As far as I know, to make it work properly I need to secure both, backend and frontend application. I consider using Let's Encrypt as the cheapest option, with certbot to refresh certificates on his own.

My question is: how many certificates do I need to issue and which servers do I need to configure? Should I configure them in GoDaddy configuration or in AWS console? Where should I install certbot? DO I need to include the private part of certificate in every single application?

Comment: Use AWS CloudFront distribution(s) in front of your applications, so that you can use free AWS Certificate Manager Issued SSL Certificates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use LetsEncrypt certificates with S3. You need to place CloudFront in front of S3, and then you can use free [AWS ACM SSL](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/) certificates. You can add the same AWS SSL certificates to the load balancers in your Elastic Beanstalk environments, or place CloudFront in front of those environments as well.